# ImageButton error onClick

Tags: android, switch-statement, imagebutton

I am calling a function click() when clicked on some imagebuttons and performing some actions.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_first_person:

        Log.i("utc","1st person");
        this.flip(R.id.btn_i);
        this.flip(R.id.btn_we);
        break;

    case R.id.btn_i:
        Log.i("utc","I clicked");
        this.change("I","play");
        break;

    case R.id.btn_we:
        Log.i("utc","We clicked");
        this.change("We","plays");
        break;

    default: Log.i("utc","default");
            Log.i("utc","asa" + v.getId());





    }
    }
```

The "btn_i" button is working fine but when i click on "btn_we" button it goes straight to default. I dont know why??

```
public void change(String person, String verb)
{
    txtUsageFirst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.utc_usage_one);
    txtUsageSecond=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.utc_usage_two);
    txtUsageFirst.setText(person);
    txtUsageSecond.setText(verb);

}
```

also when i call this flip function in the 1st case (btn_first_person) error occurs, in the btnTemp=(Button) findviewbyid(r); line [logcat doesnot show "check","1" ]

```
public void flip(Integer r)
{
    Log.d("check","enetred flip");
    Log.d("check",r.toString());
    btnTemp=(Button) findViewById(r);
    Log.d("check","1");
    if(btnTemp.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE)
    {
        Log.d("check","invisible now");
        btnTemp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("check","visible now");
        btnTemp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }



}
```

Comment: Do you set OnClickListener() at the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For flip function you are casting an ImageButton to Button and this may be producing error.

Comment: As well remove default or put `break;` after default.

Comment: yeah! you were right. thnx a lot. That solves the second problem. But what abt the first one? what could be the problem there. I mean even now after executing flip() only btn_i gets invisible and not the btn_we!!

Comment: If you dont mind can you please paste the code where you have set the Click Listener?

Comment: I dont have a clickListener. I call click function directly from xml.
android:onclick="click"